# Pandas mean() of column ignoring nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which each row has a numpy array. It looks something like this:

```
 |   Column 1     |
 |----------------|
 |   [nan, 4, 5]  |
 |   [3, 2, 6]    |
 |   [3, 3, 4].   |
```

I'm trying to get the average of those arrays, using:

```
Avg = df['Column1'].mean()
```

Even though ".mean()" skips nan by default, this is not the case here. Since the row isn't actually empty and just one value from the array is missing, I get the following result:

```
print(Avg)
> [nan, 3, 5]
```

How can I ignore the missing value from the first row?
Ideally, this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
print(Avg)
> [3, 3, 5]
```

*Note that the first average should be `(3+3)/2`, not `(3+3)/3`. So filling the arrays with zeros is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Column 1'].tolist()).mean().tolist()
Out[127]: [3.0, 3.0, 5.0]
```